# Android: Control input in EditText

Tags: android

I want to control input in EditText. If it is null I show text message "null" and if it is not null I show "not null".
I used this code below but it not work for me.

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            String aa=edittext.toString();
            if("".equalsIgnoreCase(aa)==false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "champs non vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "champs  vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also I used this but nothing.

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            String aa=edittext.toString();
            if(aa!=null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "champs non vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "champs  vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How can I do this ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Umm, where is the lowerLeftX variable coming from?  If you want to get the text in the edit text, you need to use edittext.getText().toString()

Comment: I forget to change it by edittext. String aa=edittext.toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check the `EditText` if it is empty or not you can use this :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
if(editText.getText() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString.trim()) {
    Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "champs non vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, "champs vide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```